# How to force Text::CSV to store number as text?

Tags: string, csv, perl, formatting, truncate

I am writing some perl code to create a .csv file from records in the database, using the Text::CSV module. Occasionally, one or more of the fields in my table will contain multiple repeating 0s, which will write to the CSV as a single 0. I'm trying to find out how to force the number as text format, so that all of the 0s from those fields will remain in tact.

```
    use Text::CSV_XS;

    sub write_file {
       my ($self, %params) = @_;

       my $fh = $params{fh};

       .. do stuff
       .. get database rows

       my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ sep_char => ',' });
    
       for my $row (@$rows) {
           my @fields = (
              $row->{name},
              $row->{address},
              $row->{code}
           );

           $csv->combine(@fields);

           print $fh $csv->string . "\r\n"
               or die 'Write error.';
       }
```

With this approach, everything looks good *most of the time*. But, when code comes through as "00000", it is truncated and written as "0" in my CSV.

I've investigated `$csv->types`, but this only allows the type to be defined when decoding during a parse.

I've also tried wrapping the fields in quotes using `$csv->quote(@fields)`, with no luck.

Comment: "_code comes through as "00000"_"  --- at what point can you confirm that it is still a string `00` (let's keep it at two zeros)? If you print `$row->{code}` is it multiple zeros?  I have trouble reproducing the problem: if I make up a hashref with a value of `q(00)` (quoted) string and do the rest you show -- _and don't do any number-like_  stuff on it -- it winds up as `00` in the CSV file.

Comment: In other words, what starts as a string (`my $s = q(00);` or such) stays a string, unless it is exposed to "numeric context."  None of the code you show does that, so either you are getting a number back from the database or there's more going on?

Comment: Have you tried https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#keep_meta_info ?

Comment: @zdim, thanks for your response. I did print out the contents of the fields array, or more specifically `$row->{code}` directly before the call to `$csv->combine`, and all of the 0s are correct.

I think the problem lies in Excel specifically, which is what I was using to open the CSV file. if I open the file in a text editor, all of the 0s are present.

Comment: As you might know, there are ways to deal with Excel being so "helpful". But that might be off-topic for this post, so that's all I'll comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to `always_quote()` to force the the combined fields to be quoted

```
use Text::CSV_XS;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { sep_char => ',' } );

my @fields = ( "0", "00", "000" );

$csv->combine(@fields);
print $csv->string . "\n";

$csv->always_quote(1);
$csv->combine(@fields);
print $csv->string . "\n";
```

which results in

```
0,00,000
"0","00","000"
```

Comment: I think @ComputersAreNeat was asking how to get quotes to show up, but reading the comments above might indicate that they were really asking about how to get Excel to do their bidding.

Comment: Excel converts all three of the quoted zeros as 0 by default for me

Comment: Re-reading that comment indicates that they to realize that "the problem lies in Excel"

Answer (score 1):

## Normalize your data

If the problem is that

- You want leading 0s,
- The leading zeros in your input are **NOT** significant (ie, scientific notation)

Then you can simply normalize the data with `sprintf`

```
$x = 5;
print sprintf("%05d", $x)
```

You can choose how many leading zeros you want in your output, and make all colums read the same.